# Servidor Windows com latência alta utilizando IIS

Tags: windows, iis, ping

Alguém tem ideia de como descobrir ou quais motivos que podem levar a este problema:

Possuo servidor ***Windows 2012*** rodando `IIS` com 9 sites.

Meu servidor é da ***RedeHost***. Brasileiro.

Quando dou *ping* em meu site, o valor varia muito de 16ms á *200~300ms*... E tem momentos que dão picos de *500~800ms*.

Ocorreu um problema também no dia de ontem, que o servidor parou de funcionar por total, ficou inacessível, pois o `IIS` estava consumindo toda a capacidade de rede, impossibilitando inclusive conectar via `WTS`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como solucionar o problema ou como analisar? Qual ferramenta utilizar para isso?

Comment: Você deu `ping` em outro servidor deles? O que acontece? Verificou como está o consumo de outros recursos da máquina?

Comment: Esse servidor é compartilhado?

Answer (score 0):

Olá! A resposta ICMP (ping) normalmente mede a latência de rede, independente do sistema operacional, ou do consumo do mesmo. Entretanto, o ICMP tem baixa prioridade de tráfego, então, se o seu servidor está com muito acesso, o tempo de resposta ICMP vai aumentar em função da priorização dos demais pacotes (serviços web, ftp, etc).

O que eu te sugiro é instalar uma ferramenta externa de monitoramento do servidor (utilizo o serverdensity.com, que é excelente mas pago). Com ela você vai conseguir monitorar todos os parâmetros do servidor como load, ram, disco, rede, etc. Além disso, esta ferramenta permite que você monitore os serviços externamente (como o acesso http à sua aplicação).

Desta forma, com estes dados, você poderá ver se o problema está no servidor ou se é o teu hosting que está tendo problemas.

Coisas que você deve considerar:

1) Como tu já falaste que o teu IIS estava aumentando muito a load do servidor, posso te dizer que o problema está no alto tráfego da tua aplicação. Hora de aumentar o servidor ou otimizar a aplicação.

2) Pode ser que você tenha algum bug na aplicação que está gerando load alta. Ás vezes alguma consulta de banco de dados sem índices pode gerar este problema.

3) Você pode estar sofrendo algum ataque DDOS. Fale com seu datacenter para avaliarem.

4) Você já verificou se não há algum vírus no seu servidor ? Quando se trata de servidor Windows é indispensável ver isso.

Tenho certeza que se você seguir estas verificações, o problema vai aparecer.

Boa sorte! Abraço.